# File not uploading into folder using php on aws EC2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to upload images into folder on aws server. I have done all the things like permission and given full directory path.But I got bool(false) from **move_upload_file** function.

**/var/www/html/backend/images/event/**

Here is my code :

```
$nimage2 = "images/event/xyz.jpg";
$e = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/backend/'.$nimage2);
```

**It will return false.**

Please help me out.

**Want to know : Is it possible or I have to choose s3 bucket for this?**

Comment: Check the rights the user you use to connect has. Try creating a separate which has sufficient rights to do this.